# Why jQuery draggable() doesn't work on form

Tags: jquery, forms, draggable

```
<form action="">
    <input type="button" value="testing" >
</form>

$('form').draggable();
```

**Check jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/HQBrw/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its working here:

define `height` and `width` of form and also use `jQuery UI 1.8.16`

see the [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/HQBrw/16/)

Comment: The form is dynamically generated. i don't have to define width and height to the form. I want the user to be able to click on the button itself and drag.

Comment: @Pinkie, atleast use `latest UI`. you can check the demo after its working even after removing `width and height`,you can set `border` atleast

Comment: I guess this is the only way to drag a button. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would put a form in a div and drag the div rather than form:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/HQBrw/10/)

Comment: I don't want to drag the div and don't want to wrap the form with a div. I want to be able to click on the button and drag it

Answer (score 1):

By default input (and button) [is disabled from draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel) (and sortable). You can disable this behavior by setting cancel to something else:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="button" value="testing" >
</form>
$('form').draggable({cancel:''});
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/soderlind/xbBNb/

The side effect is, you will not be able to click your button :/